# SQLServer 2012: Non-Unique index definition during table create?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

Can I create a non-unique index during the CREATE TABLE statement in SQLServer 2012?  I've found some pre-release documents referencing this, but when I try it, it doesn't work.  It looks like that didn't make it into the release, but I'd like to get a more definitive answer.

The document indicated you could do something like:

```
create table rm.test (
  t1 int not null,
  t2 int,
  constraint pk_t1 primary key (t1),
  index idx_t2 (t2)
)
```

However, it complains on the "index".  Is there a way to do this or am I stuck with doing a CREATE INDEX after the table is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The inline index definition is new for SQL Server 2014.

In this case you can do

```
CREATE TABLE rm.test
  (
     t1 INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_t1 PRIMARY KEY,
     t2 INT,
     CONSTRAINT idx_t2 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (t2, t1)
  )
```

Which [actually creates the same thing](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx) though.

Primary keys are the clustered index by default and the CI key gets appended to non unique non clustered keys implicitly to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you, @Martin Smith.  Unfortunately, the index I need isn't unique.  I'll just add the index create to the script.

Comment: @JerseyMike - I don't think you understood the answer. The primary key is guaranteed unique so if you append it to the NCI key the combination of the two columns is guaranteed unique. SQL Server actually does this behind the scenes anyway if you were to create a non unique non clustered index. i.e. For this table definition `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (t2, t1)` and `NONCLUSTERED  INDEX(t2)` both wind up being structured exactly the same.

Comment: You are right, @Martin Smith.  I didn't understand yet. I commented before following the link and reading Kalen's blog post. Thank you again.